# model.frame, UseMethod, and R bytecode reference -- what is this?

Tags: r, class, bytecode

General context:  I'm trying to find the code that dictates how the model.frame command in R recognizes the class of its argument and subsequently calls one of the model.frame methods.

When I run "model.frame" to reveal its R source code, I get the following:

```
> model.frame
function (formula, ...) 
UseMethod("model.frame")
<bytecode: 0x21a04c8>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Specific question:  What is "bytecode: 0x21a04c8" telling me?  Is it potentially useful in my context?

Comment: Do you just want to know how the dispatch works, or do you really need the R source code for it?  (That is, what exactly is your context?)

Comment: I'm interested in the R source for the dispatch, I think.  But more directly to the point of the question, I wonder what "bytecode: 0x21a04c8" means.

Comment: All base packages have been byte compiled since 2.14.0 I believe. Simply googling `r byte compiler` would have probably told you this. It is not relavent to finding the actual code inside that function.

Comment: [Here](http://homepage.stat.uiowa.edu/~luke/R/compiler/compiler.pdf) you go! Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Use `methods(model.frame)` to see what methods exist. In general, you'll be using `model.frame.default` nearly all the time.